# Two difference version of dependencies in pom

Tags: java, maven, struts, apache-commons

I have the following dependensies in my pom.xml :

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-validator</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-validator</artifactId>
                <version>1.1.3</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>struts</groupId>
                <artifactId>struts</artifactId>
                <version>1.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
 </dependencyManagement>
```

My goal is to use more later version of commons-validator. Namely, I am going to use DomainValidator from 1.4.0 version.

I tried to change version, but struts throws exception like this:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/validator/ValidatorResourcesInitializer
```

In the latest version of commons-validator class ValidatorResourcesInitializer is simply missing.

**Will be good to know whether it possible to fix this one without changes of struts version.
Could you suggest any alternative libraries for validation domain and IP addresses?**

Comment: You probably also need to upgrade the struts or you are stuck with the commons-validator version ```1.1.4```(it is the one used in struts 1.1) see the pom file: http://search.maven.org/remotecontent?filepath=struts/struts/1.1/struts-1.1.pom
Anyway struts 1.1 is over 8 years old. You cannot expect the latest libraries to work with it.

Comment: Eh, we have 100+ struts pages. It's really almost impossible

Comment: You could try to include both versions of the commons-validator using some renaming of the dependencies. There's a plugin for that, but I haven't tried it: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

Comment: class `ValidatorResourcesInitializer` was depricated and removed from commons-validator, so you can stay with old verson or upgrade both validator and struts

Comment: You're learning the pain of software -maintenance-; legacy software uses legacy technology and you can't just run an upgrade script in 99% of the cases. The only thing I can offer as a suggestion is to try and extract the class you want to use from the newer version of the library and just add it to the code base of your own application; if you keep the licensing headers in tact that should be no problem. I'm not saying it is easy because the class may use several other classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found guava validator com.google.common.net.InternetDomainName based on much newer version of RFC-3490.